# Having trouble installing Prism in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, prism

When I try to install Prism in my Xamarin application in visual studio I get this error 
"[nuget.orgUnable to load the service index for source http://prism.azureedge.net/main.mrep. The content at 'http://prism.azureedge.net/main.mrep' is not a valid JSON object. Unexpected charater encountered while parsing value: <.Path ", line 0, position0.]"

Comment: Can you also add the version of Prism and Xamarin to the question.

Comment: I have Xamarin version 6.3 and I am trying to install Prism version 6.3.0

Comment: It is because the content here: http://prism.azureedge.net/main.mrep is in xml format. Not sure if this helps: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4624

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I'm entirely sure what you're doing, but let me try to clarify some things for you.

The URL http://prism.azureedge.net/main.mrep is **ONLY** meant to be added as an Extensions Repository Source for Visual Studio Mac. It has nothing to do with NuGet and is not compatible with any other version of Visual Studio. That feed provides the Visual Studio Mac Extension to provide the Prism Project & Item Templates as well as several code snippets.

If you are looking for the Prism CI Feed to take advantage of the latest Prism build you need to add https://www.myget.org/F/prism/api/v3/index.json as a NuGet Package Source.